# Power series convergence question

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Does there exist a sequence $c_{n}$ of complex numbers such that
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} z^{n}
$$
has radius of convergence $R = \infty$, but for all other sequences $c_{n}'$ of complex numbers such that $|c_{n}' / c_{n} | \to \infty$ implies that
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n}' z^{n}
$$
does not converge for at least one $z \in C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a sequence does not exist. For every power series

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n,$$

its derivative

$$f'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot c_n z^{n-1}$$

has the same radius of convergence, and so does the power series of $g(z) = z\cdot f'(z)$:

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot c_n z^n.$$

$\lvert n c_n\rvert/\lvert c_n\rvert \to +\infty$ is clear, and $c_n' = nc_n \neq c_n$ for $n \neq 1$ and $c_n \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A remark: in your example $c'_{n} = (n+1) c_{n+1}$. Therefore your answer is not yet complete.

Comment: @Vincent That's why I multiplied with $z$ and used $z\cdot f'(z)$. Clarified that.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.